# Chen's Notation Diagram

Tags: database, associations, relationship, entity-relationship, erd

Before starting to develop anything, I made a draft of a ER diagram using Chen's notation, when developing the web page I had to change some stuff on the database, and at the end I got this ER diagram:

[image]

Between "booking" and "staff" tables I have a relational table "assign".
But between "booking" and "parts" I have this "cost" which I believe its the relational one, but I dont know how to represent it on Chen's notation diagram. Can someone give me a help? :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In this physical ERD diagram, which shows how primary and foreign keys are used to implement the relationships.

From the conceptual point of view:

- `assign` implements a many-to-many relation between `staff` and `booking`;
- `cost` implements a many-to-many relation between `booking` and `part` that provides additional information about the combination between booking and parts.

In Chen's notation:

- `assign` would be represented with a [simple losange](https://www.vertabelo.com/blog/chen-erd-notation/) for relationship and a cardinality M, N.
- `cost` would also be representad with a many-to-many relationship losange.  But in addition, you'd show the relationship's attributes (e.g. `quantity`, `cost`, `description`) as additional [ellipses connected to the relationship](https://www.conceptdraw.com/examples/what-is-chen-notation)

You could also consider to use [associative entities](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38367232/3723423) instead of realationships, especially for `cost`.  It has the advantage of suggesting that there's a table behind.  But it's not required in your model, unless `cost` could have relationships with other tables (which would be easy since there's a `cost_id`)