# Is it possible for an associative entity to have a subtype?

Tags: inheritance, entity, relation, erd

I am creating an EERD. Currently I have two enties, `Order` and `Product` which is link by an associative entity `Order`. I classified orders into two types, `WalkIn` and `OnCall`.

But is itpossible for the associative entity to have a subtype?

Answer (score 0):

A diagram would be helpful for this question, since the wording is ambiguous about whether `Order` is the associative entity or if there is another one that was not named in the question.  Here an answer for the two cases:

**Hyothesis 1**: `Order` and `Product` are entities and the relation between the two is an [associative entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity). In this case, order is a normal entity that can be subtyped as you want in an EERD.

**Hypothesis 2**:: `Product` and, say `Customer`, are entities , and the relation between the two is an associative entity called `Order`.  An association entity is [at the same time](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/122538.122542) an association like any others, an entity like any others. This means that it can have its attributes, it [could be further associated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38366466/3723423), and it can be specialised (subtyped) if you're in one of the EERD notation.

***Remark**: there is as far as I know no single authoritative definition of EERD, and in academic papers, there are several representations that are used.  As soon as you start thinking of subtyping,  I'd strongly advise to consider UML instead of EERD: it is a very well defined  standard ([freely downloadable](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/)), with plenty of books which all share the same understanding and representation (start with Martin Fowler's "UML distilled" for a quick introduction).  You could represent in an UML class diagram everything that you can represent in an EERD and even more.*